# Capturing data before it's changed in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

My application has a databound gridview control.  When someone changes anything in a cell, the backing datasource is changed.  When the user saves the changes, I'm basically just getting using:

```
var changes = ((DataTable)this.bindingSource1.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

With the `changes` collection, I can then update the appropriate database tables.

Now, however, the user wants there to be a log to contain before AND after data.  I could just make a copy of the datasource and hold onto it and compare what was changed, then write out a log with the before and after.  But, isn't there some other way that won't require me to keep a copy of the entire datasource?  I'd like to only keep a *before* image of data that was actually changed, instead of the whole datasource pre-changes.

I know there's an event that I could use that fires when a cell is changed.  Is there a way to grab the original pre-changed data by using this event?  I can't think of how, though, since the event only fires if the cell is changed.

Saving the entire datasource seems impractical, so I'm hoping there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    dgv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);

    void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Work here, this is called before the cell change has been comitted
    }
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on this event

Comment: Looks exactly like what I needed.  Thanks so much!